# Printing a series of dataframes in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have a list of dataframes in the following form:

`[dfs] = [df1, df2, df3, ..... dfn]`

I want to print the head of each dataframe in the list through a for loop.
I tried with both the `print` command, and writing directly the df, but all I get is an ugly looking array and not in the form of a dataframe.

See below, thanks.

```
for i in range (0, int(max_range_v)):
    dfs[i]
```

with the above I get nothing.

I also tried the following:

```
i = 1
dfs[i].head()
```

this works, but when i embed it in the loop it doesnt work anymore.

How can i fix it?

Ideally i would like to get something the outcome like a good looking dataframe printed through pandas.
Can't reproduce it here.... well i don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print two dataframe with the same format as pandas you can use this library:

```
from IPython.display import display 
display(df1.head()) 
display(df2.head())
```

And for case you just have to do this function in your loop